# How to use ActionInvoker.InvokeAction? - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC ASP.NET and needed to call an action from one controller in an action of another controller. There I created object of controller and called my required action as below,

```
controllerOne co = new controllerOne();

co.requiredFunction();
```

but one of my senior advised me to not use this approach, which kills the MVC pattern use its given  `ActionInvoker.InvokeAction()` function to call function of other controller and I am using now as below,

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    this.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext(
        this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, new controllerOne()), 
        "requiredAction");
}
```

This works fine, but I don't know if the way I am using `ActionInvoker.InvokeAction()` is correct. I searched to find any example but I could find any.

So my question is: **Am I using it correctly?**

Comment: Can you show some extra information on why you need to call an `Action` from another Controller?

Comment: you dont need to create new controllercontext it is available as property on Controller Class, so use this.controllercontext instead of creating new instance  ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(this.ControllerContext,"actionname")

Answer (score 2):

To do this many people would create a service that encapsulates this `requiredFunction` and inject the service through it's interface into both controllers

Comment: OK I agree with your views, but my question was which way is better to call function of one controller from function of an other.

Comment: this would be what you would call an anti-pattern.  there is no better way, they're all bad.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var ctrl= new MyController();
ctrl.ControllerContext = ControllerContext;
//call action
 return ctrl.Action();
```